# change header after login in yii

Tags: yii, header, http-headers

How do I change the header after login, or is using another header even the right way to do it? Meaning there would be two different headers(guest/user). I've searched for it, mostly about redirects of the entire page, not what I am looking for.

Sorry for the noob question. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two files in your view with guest_header.php and user_header.php when user is logged in user user_header.php as your header file in your layout or simply use guest_header.php
and in your column layout use it like below

```
when user is logged in 

<?php if(Yii::app()->user->id): ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/user_header.php'); ?>
when user is guest
<?php else: ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/guest_header.php'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
Added this line
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</div><!-- content -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit endcontent was not there that's why it was not working